# Yum on CentOS 7 repositories may be broken

Tags: centos, yum

Just got CentOS 7 on a new server and I went `yum install httpd` and it went fine. Afterwards I went `yum install mysql-server` and I got `No package mysql-server available`.

I haven't messed up with the configuration files. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB is the community-developed fork of MySQL:

```
sudo yum install mariadb-server mariadb
```

[MariaDB is the replacement for MySQL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ReplaceMySQLwithMariaDB), forked over concerns that Oracle may make MySQL a closed-source project.